# How can I connect metal components so that they can swivel?

Tags: appliances, bolts, chair

I am making a standing wheelchair. This involves metal pipe components needing to be able to rotate. Can I use a regular bolt and nut to achieve this? or would there be too much wearing because there would be a lot of rotating. A commercial standing wheelchair is shown below, it seems like it uses just a regular bolt and nut but im not sure.

[image: manual standing wheelchair]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to visit a bike shop.  They have bolts that should fit and which would b quite durable.

Answer (score 5):

A [shoulder bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_and_bolt_types#Shoulder_bolt) provides a smooth cylindrical section and a threaded end. It is designed to act as both a shaft and fastener.

A [Nylon lock nut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locknut) allows adjusting the slack in the connection without worrying about the nut falling off.

Answer (score 3):

If just moving the two pieces by hand, then just a bolt and nut combination will be enough.

If moving the two pieces with weight on them, then can use a sleeve(a small pipe) with the bolt inside the sleeve.

For something like a wheel chair or anything that is close to a body, a round head bolt with a locking cap nut is usually good.  They leave the ends sticking out smooth, and the locking nut does not need to be tight to stay on the bolt.  You do not need to tighten the nut and squeeze the rotating parts tight.

Comment: Thank you, what size/thickness of boltwould you reckon is suitable?

Comment: @Ben   I like to over build stuff, but something about the size of 5/16 to 3/8 inch diameter, grade 5 should be enough, just long enough(cut if needed) to place a nut on.

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about wear on the bolt (or the bolt holes), use a sleeve in the hole and run the bolt through the sleeve.  Nylon, delrin, teflon, or similar.  Then if the sleeve wears, you just replace it.